# "Table x:Y.z: The user 123@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table project_x:y.z."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to access the BigQuery view using dataflow pipeline written in python and storing resultant records into CSV file on GCS. I have authorized view permission granted but still I am getting error T

> able project_x:dataset_y.table_z: The user
>   123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have
>   bigquery.tables.get permission for table project_x:dataset_y.table_z.

I Tried it running with Directrunner as well as DataflowRunner but still not getting resolve. Any resolvable solutions are welcome

Comment: The service account that Dataflow is using needs access to the dataset that contains the view. The corresponding view needs access the dataset for which the underlying table that it's referencing in its SQL. First, make sure this is all set up correctly.

Comment: @GrahamPolley I have given respective access to the service account that Dataflow is using. Interesting part of your input is I have to also check permissions for the tables which are used inside view. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#authorize_the_view_to_access_the_source_dataset

Comment: Have you tried running the Dataflow job directly on the table ?

Comment: @VikramShinde Yes, If I run the same dataflow code on BQ table then it gives me expected result. But gives error If I am running same code on BQ view.